# How to read from file correctly

Tags: c

**What's the problem of this code.**

```
   do {
    ch = fgetc(file);
    printf("%c", ch);
} while (ch != "\n");
fclose(file);
```

In file i just have "Hallo, world\n" and when i try to read info i have a infinity loop.
If i change to `ch != EOF` I have a correct answer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: In fact, you should test for either LF or EOF... Not all text files will end with a newline character...

Comment: What is `ch`? Is this variable defined as an `int` or `char`? This is important. Please provide a [mre] (as described above) so we don't have to make any guesses.

Comment: You should check whether `ch` is `EOF` before printing `ch`. Otherwise, if `ch` has the value `EOF`, then you will be converting this special value to a character code and printing it, which you probably do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *string* "\n" is not the same as the *character* '\n'.

In the comparison `ch != "\n"` you are comparing ch (which should be [declared an int](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm)) with a pointer (a pointer to a string of chars), which isn't what you intended.

Comment: UV before question is closed as "typo"...

Comment: Nice catch, can you also explain why? `""` points to a string and compare to an address not a char..